# Altair: adding sorting destroys chart

Tags: python, visualization, altair

The following code produces a column chart in which the `y` axis grows in the wrong direction.

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x = alt.X('pub_date', timeUnit='month'),
    y = alt.Y('sum(has_kw)',  ),
)
```

[image]

I wanted to correct it as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/58326269, and changed my code to

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x = alt.X('pub_date', timeUnit='month'),
    y = alt.Y('sum(has_kw)', sort=alt.EncodingSortField('y', order='descending') ),
)
```

But now altair produces a strange diagram, see [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF1Vc.png).

[image: here]

That is, `sum(has_kw)` is calculated wrong. Why this, and how to correct it?

Comment: try this: `x = alt.X('pub_date:O', timeUnit='month'),` See [info](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/timeunit.html#):

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know exactly without seeing a sample of your data but you could try one of the following (based on the example you linked). This first approach is similar to what you tried already:

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Compute x^2 + y^2 across a 2D grid
x, y = np.meshgrid(range(0, 3), range(0, 3))
z = x ** 2 + y ** 2

# Convert this grid to columnar data expected by Altair
source = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': x.ravel(),
    'y': y.ravel(),
    'z': z.ravel()
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_rect().encode(
    x='x:O',
    y=alt.Y('y:O', sort='descending'),
    color='z:Q'
)
```

[image]

This second approaches simply reverses the axes without sorting it and might be more compatible with your data:

```
alt.Chart(source).mark_rect().encode(
    x='x:O',
    y=alt.Y('y:O', scale=alt.Scale(reverse=True)),
    color='z:Q'
)
```

[image]